# Solr not accepting the "yyyy-MM-dd" date formating with tdate (TrieDateField) field

Tags: solr, date-formatting, date-parsing

I am using `Solr 7.7.2` version. I have defined field called `date_test` with type `tdate(TrieDateField)` as given below inside the `{core}/conf/schema.xml` file

```
 <field name="date_test" type="tdate" docValues="true" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true" />
```

Inside the `{core}/conf/solrconfig.xml` I can see this date format is defined here,

```
<updateProcessor class="solr.ParseDateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory" name="parse-date">
    <arr name="format">
      <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ</str>
      <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSZ</str>
      <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS</str>
      <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSS</str>
      <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ</str>
      <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss</str>
      <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ</str>
      <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm</str>
      <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ</str>
      <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSSZ</str>
      <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS</str>
      <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS</str>
      <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ</str>
      <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</str>
      <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ</str>
      <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</str>
      <str>yyyy-MM-dd</str>
    </arr>
  </updateProcessor>
```

Also, I can see this bean is used inside the `updateRequestProcessorChain` as given below,

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema" default="${update.autoCreateFields:false}"
           processor="uuid,remove-blank,field-name-mutating,parse-boolean,parse-long,parse-double,parse-date,add-schema-fields">
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
  </updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

Now, when I try to post the document using curl with `yyyy-MM-dd` format like below,

```
 curl -X POST -d '{"add":{ "doc":{"id":"delete.me1","messageid":"message.delete.me1","date_test":"2020-01-10"}}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://{ip}:8983/solr/test-data/update?commit=true
```

This give me error like

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":4},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"ERROR: [doc=message.delete.me1] Error adding field 'date_test'='2020-01-10' msg=Invalid Date String:'2020-01-10'",
    "code":400}}
```

I am trying to understand why this format is not accepted even if we have format defined inside the `ParseDateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory`

Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your processor chain is not enabled :`default="${update.autoCreateFields:false}"`.

You might need to check if `update.autoCreateFields` is set in your config because it actually fallback to false. You need to set it to true :

```
bin/solr config -c <collection> -p <port> -action set-user-property -property update.autoCreateFields -value true
```

Comment: Hello @Eric : Thanks for your time, if I try to do so, I am getting status `400` with error `This IndexSchema is not mutable.`

Comment: You are using Solr in schemaless mode ?